# Adding string Value with int value, both are numaric

Tags: php, mysql

I have stored some numaric data with **varchar** datatype in database, something like ( **00005** ) as studentid

After retrieving it from database, i want to auto increment it by **1** like below:

**echo $data['studentid']+1;** ---> but the result will be only **6**, the zero's are removed, because it being changed from string to integer.

My Question is that: Is there any possiblity that the result would be like **00006** not only **6**?

Please help me regarding the issue and advise me about my mistakes and suggest me for better ways to do it.

Comment: is the length of the string fixed, or there could be a string like 0005 and one other like 00000003 ?

Comment: The answer to your question is correctly given below. However, if the student id is a number I am curious why you would store it as a varchar in your database. You better have a very good reason not to use an integer type :-)

Comment: i have stored as **varchar** because the **int** datatype does not leading zeros

Comment: Like @CompuChip says, it would be better to store it as an `int` (this is neater and allows sorting etc.) and then use my answer whenever you either display it or increment it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
echo sprintf("%06s", $data['studentid']+1);
```

Comment: `echo sprintf()` is an "antipattern". There is absolutely no reason that anyone should ever write `echo sprintf()` in any code for any reason -- it should be `printf()` without `echo` every time.